# Android Studio different sizes in devices

Tags: android, kotlin, responsive-design, responsive, android-constraintlayout

i am new to android studio and i am trying to fit the image every device but its smaller in high density devices how can i solve this.

[this is my physical device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEgU0.png)

[this my virtual device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV5KR.png)

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_60sdp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/glancesanslight"
        android:text="WELCOME"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#00A083"
    
        android:textSize="@dimen/_40sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/glancesansregular"
        android:letterSpacing=".15"
        android:text="TO CATLET"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#007863"
    
        android:textSize="@dimen/_30sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_32sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_60sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/mainartwork"
        tools:flow_horizontalAlign="start" />
    
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_32sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_rect"
        android:fontFamily="@font/oswaldbold"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:text="BAŞLA"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_28sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

\</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout\>
```

i've tried using sdp and constraint layout but didnt get to work. I dont know much about the constraints like i said i am fully beginner in android studio, i have different image sizes for ldpi, mdpi ext, but it looks smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two layouts look basically the same, it's just the size of the graphic that's giving you problems, right?

The issue is that your graphic has a size defined which looks correct on the test device (with a particular resolution and density), but not on your other device (with a different resolution/density). When you use an `ImageView` with `wrap_content`, you're allowing its intrinsic size to define how big *the view should be* in your layout.

Ideally, if you're using `ConstraintLayout`, you'd use *constraints* to define the size of your views, including that `ImageView`. Then you'd make the *drawable* fit that defined area, not the other way around, if you see what I mean!

---

There's a few ways you could do that - here's one (I'm just going to add the important attributes):

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_60sdp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"

        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1.0"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"

        app:srcCompat="@drawable/mainartwork"/>
```

So there are a few things going on here:

- the width and height are set to `0dp` so they're completely controlled by the constraints
- the width is controlled by the horizontal constraints, which pin either side to the edges of the parent, with a fixed margin on the right eating into that width
- the height is controlled by the `constraintDimensionRatio` attribute, which is a factor of the width - in this case *1.0*, it matches the width, so the view is a square
- `scaleType` is set to `fitCenter`, which scales the image so it fits the view while maintaining its aspect ratio

The result is you have a square `ImageView` with its dimensions defined by its width. If that's wasteful (e.g. the image is wider than it is tall) then you can use the appropriate aspect ratio for the image, instead of `1.0`. `fitCenter` ensures that whatever the size of the view, the image will fit inside it without distortion (you can use `fitXY` if you want it to stretch to fill the area).

---

Unfortunately, I'm not sure there's a way to make it size automatically to fit the image, besides `wrap_content` (which prevents you from using constraints to control the layout). And there are more ways to define your layout, not just a fixed-dp margin (which would look different on devices with different widths, especially if you go landscape layout).

One thing you might want to consider is using your title text as an anchor:

[image: The layout posted in the question]

See how the edge of the graphic is basically aligned with the right edge of the text? Instead of constraining to the *parent's* right edge, maybe constrain to the text edge instead. It depends how your layout is designed! Should the graphic always be *60dp* (or whatever) from the edge of the screen? Or should it always align with the text? When working with responsive designs, you need to think about what should happen when you have more (or less!) space, where things should go, and what the relationships between the different components are. Broadly, should *element X* be positioned and sized relative to *element Y*, or should it be relative to the screen, the available space?

There's a lot to learn on this, but have a look at the docs on [supporting different screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes?hl=en) and the section after on responsive layouts. Maybe this [ConstraintLayout tutorial](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout) which shows some of the tools you have available! And don't forget you can use different devices in the Layout Designer preview window - check how your design looks on different screen sizes, densities (like phone vs tablet) etc.

---

And just a quick overview on the *dp* and *sp* thing. *dp* is a way of defining fixed sizes that look *basically* the same on any device. *160dp* is about an inch on the screen, for every device. So when you define a *60dp* margin, that's a fixed size of about *1cm*.

On some devices, that's a decent chunk of the screen - on others, it's a very small part of it. On a watch, that's half of it! This is why you need to keep this variability in mind when you're building responsive designs (and, for the watch example, you might want a completely different layout)

*sp* is like *dp* but it scales according to the user's system font size settings. So this is usually used *for text* so they can control how big it is to make it more comfortable to read - when you're using *sp* values, you always need to test what your layouts look like at different size settings, especially the larger ones!

But you don't *have to* use *sp* for all text. Your title above the graphic for example - that's more of a design element, right? You want it to be a certain size, to take up a certain amount of space. It's almost like a logo. And besides - it's already pretty big! Does it need to scale larger to become readable? I'd argue probably not - anyone who needs that is probably gonna have trouble with the rest of your app, because it's unlikely the rest of the text will ever get close to that size.

So in this case, I'd probably use *dp* so you can consistently lay out your design there (*sp* on the button is fine - normal text elements should always use *sp* for accessibility). I'm not sure what the `_60sdp` `dimen` value is there (*sp*? *dp*?) but it's better to use the correct name so it's clear.

---

Also in general, you wouldn't use `dimen` resources for explicit values like that - if it's *60dp*, you may as well just write *60dp*! Resources are for things like `@dimen/horizontalMargin` or `@dimen/titleTextSize` - actual *attributes* that might be commonly shared across elements, or might vary depending on things like screen size.

By defining the *actual value* in your resources, you can change everything that *uses* that attribute by updating the value in one place. And having a named resource means it's clearer *why* that text is a particular size, or a margin has a particular width - you're describing its purpose, basically. You're getting the worst of both worlds defining a resource called `@dimen/60dp`, it's more work for none of the benefits!

(Although if you're working on a fixed grid idea where everything is one of a fixed set of values, like *8dp*, *16dp*, *32dp* etc and you want to define *those*, I could see that. But even then it might be better to name them differently, just so it's clearer what you're doing and why. Just pointing it out since you're new to this!)

Comment: First of all thank you so much for your response, it worked perfectly and i think i might understand the idea, if i understand correctly i should use, constraints to fit the image not with the wrap content or fixed size, i was doing that but i didnt know how to scale to image, but the scale dimension ratio is worked well, it did what i need. And the dimen thing is i did some research about responsive values and there was a dependency called sdp and the page shows how to use it and i did what they said thats why, in conclusion thank you again for your response, it solved my problem :)

Comment: @KadirKantar yeah drawables have a specific size (usually in *dp* - you can open them to take a look) and if you make the `ImageView` use `wrap_content`, it will size to fit that drawable. If you give the `ImageView` a different size, the drawable inside it will still be drawn at its original size by default. You have to use `scaleType` to make it do any scaling

Answer (score 1):

For Different screen size, It's better to create provides different layout designs for different screen sizes. Can assign different bitmap drawables for small, medium, high, and extra high density screens as well

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // normal screen size
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // large screen size


res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

The following code in the Manifest supports all dpis.

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
          android:normalScreens="true" 
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:xlargeScreens="true"
          android:anyDensity="true" />
```